# How to call html file using ajax in coffeescript with ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm working on a project with ruby on rails and I want to render a html file on click function using Ajax in coffee-script. My html file is placed in view folder.

Coffee-script Code

```
showdialog = (num1='',title,wid=700,fixed='false') ->
   #$ -> showdi = $(num1).dialog(height: 600 , width: wid, model: true , title: title ) # disable UI popup
   title == "My Profile"  
   $.ajax(
       url: '/main.html'
       cache: false
   ).done (html) ->
       $('#jobForm .modal-header span').html title
       $('#jobForm .modal-body').html html
      return true
window.showdialog = showdialog
```

showdialog is my function which is call after the click on button. Everything works but ajax not render the file it shows file not found in console. So my question is where i place html file then ajax will render it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ajax call to:

```
$('.show_html_button').click(function () {
   $.ajax(
       url: '/main.js'
   )}
```

and in you main.js file, write:

```
$('#jobForm').append('<%= j render('main.html') %>');
window.showdialog = showdialog
```

This is just a rough idea. For details you can follow [this link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=asciicast)

**UPDATE:**

For an easier solution, You can also create a hidden `div`, say "modal".

```
<h4>
  = link_to 'Details', your_main_method_path, data: {remote: true}, item_details: true
</h4>
```

Then in your controller, on the main action:

```
def main
    respond_to {|format| format.js}
end
```

And in your controller_name views folder, create a file main.js(.coffee):

$('#modal').html('<%= j(render partial: "main") %>');
$('#modal').modal('show');
This is just the idea, you have to make it compatible with your code.

Comment: I dont want to change main.html file to main.js file because main.html contains pure html so why should i change into js file??

Comment: actually you don't need to change the html file. But ajax call will return you main.js and in main.js file you will be rendering the main.html

Comment: place it under views/your_controller_name/main.js

Comment: I have edited the answer. see the update section for easier solution

Comment: XHRGEThttp://localhost:3000/mainhelp.js?_=1543562149169
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 82ms] same issue with previous code

Comment: what is your controller name? It is looking for js file on your root directory and the file is not there. in your ajax call url: '/main.js' path should match to exact file path

Comment: see the updated answer. and try that. that is way easier that first one